# Has anyone seen this formula that I proved? $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n \choose n}{2n - 2m \choose n - m} = 4^m$

Tags: combinatorics, limits

I'm a high-schooler from the Netherlands. I developed the following formula, and I proved it:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n \choose n}{2n - 2m \choose n - m} = 4^m$$

Has anyone already seen my formula or does somebody know whether it already has been proven or not? I would like to call this 'Groen's first law' :) if it's still unknown.

Thank you and have a nice day!
Jari

Comment: Maths doesn't have laws, it would be Groen's theorem.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. Something that include "limit" and "binomial coefficients" would be better.

Comment: Not to discourage you, but this is a direct consequence of the known fact: $$\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Comment: Good work discovering the result, though.  (+1)

Comment: Thank you jjagmath, didn't know that. It's always nice to learn! Indeed, then it's easy to see that my statement is true. Thanks @lulu for the encouragement :)

Comment: This really isn't a good place to just announce a result.

Comment: My "first law" that I discovered was $(n+1)(n-1) = n^2-1$. Even though it was (obviously) already long-time known, I still kind of think of it as "mine". Hope you get the same pleasure from "your" result, and congrats!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I proved $\sin 30^\circ = \frac 12$ when I was just learning triangle geometry in $6$-th grade by gluing two 30-60-90 right triangles together to get an equilateral and I never stopped bragging about it since then.

Comment: We'd (I think) love to see **your** proof, rather than others posting their own. Please post it as an answer!

Comment: Congratulations! It suffices to prove your formula for $m=1$ and then iterate $m$ times. For $m=1$ the ratio simplifies to $${2n(2n-1)\over n^2}={2(2n-1)\over n}$$ I wonder if there is a combinatorial explanation of the result.

Comment: You might enjoy this little puzzle which features central binomial coefficients: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478014/207316

Answer (score 12):

Congratulations! As others have said, this is a straightforward consequence of very classical stuff such as [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$ or the [known asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth) ${2n \choose n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ (which also follows from Stirling's but can be proven in other ways). Stirling's approximation is a powerful tool and can be proven in several interesting ways which you may enjoy learning about (some of which do a better or worse job of explaining what the heck that $2 \pi$ is doing there); see, for example, [this blog post by Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula/).

However since you likely don't know either of these results that is likely not how you proved it. And in fact a much simpler argument is available (which we could guess based on the fact that no square roots or $\pi$s appear in this result), which I'm betting is similar to what you did. Write the quantity we're interested in as $f(n)$, suppressing the dependence on $m$ since it's fixed anyway. We just cancel the factorials:

$$\begin{align*} f(n) = \frac{ {2n \choose n} }{ {2n-2m \choose n-m} } &= \frac{2n! (n-m)!^2}{(2n-2m) n!^2} \\
 &= \frac{2n(2n-1) \dots (2n-2m+1)}{n^2(n-1)^2 \dots (n-m+1)^2} \end{align*}.$$

And now we can divide the numerator and the denominator by $n^{2m}$, which gives

$$f(n) = \frac{2 \left( 2 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \dots \left( 2 - \frac{2m-1}{n} \right)}{\left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^2 \left( 1 - \frac{2}{n} \right)^2 \dots \left( 1 - \frac{m-1}{n} \right)^2}.$$

Taking $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \frac{2^{2m}}{1} = 4^m$$

as desired. This is all that's necessary, no Stirling or anything else.

---

Working more carefully can give us a more precise asymptotic as follows. First we note that half of the terms in the numerator are even terms of the form $2n - 2k$ and we can divide those by the corresponding terms $n - k$ in the denominator. This gives

$$f(n) = 2^m \frac{(2n-1)(2n-3) \dots (2n - 2m+1)}{n(n-1) \dots (n-m+1)}.$$

Next we'll divide each remaining term in the numerator by the corresponding term in the denominator, which gives

$$f(n) = 2^m \left( 2 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \left( 2 - \frac{1}{n-1} \right) \dots \left( 2 - \frac{1}{n-m+1} \right)$$

or alternatively

$$f(n) = 4^m \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2n} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2(n-1)} \right) \dots \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2(n-m+1)} \right).$$

To estimate this somewhat mysterious product we can argue as follows. First, if $0 \le x, y \le 1$ we have $(1 - x)(1 - y) = 1 - x - y + xy \ge 1 - x - y$. Inducting on this inequality gives the following result: if $0 \le x_i \le 1$ then

$$(1 - x_1) (1 - x_2) \dots (1 - x_n) \ge 1 - x_1 - x_2 - \dots - x_n.$$

This gives us a lower bound

$$f(n) \ge 4^m \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2(n-1)} - \dots - \frac{1}{2(n-m+1)} \right)$$

which is a good bound as long as $m$ is small compared to $n$. In particular with this bound we can now analyze the behavior as $m$ is also allowed to go to infinity but more slowly than $n$. For an upper bound we have the inequality $1 - x \le e^{-x}$ which gives

$$(1 - x_1)(1 - x_2) \dots (1 - x_n) \le \exp \left( - x_1 - x_2 - \dots - x_n \right)$$

which gives an upper bound

$$f(n) \le 4^m \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2(n-1)} - \dots - \frac{1}{2(n-m+1)} \right).$$

For both of these bounds we see that it's important to get a bound on the quantity $g(n) = \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2(n-1)} + \dots + \frac{1}{2(m-1)}$. For $m$ small compared to $n$ we can use a pretty crude bound: bounding based on the smallest resp. largest term of this sum gives

$$\frac{m}{2n} \le g(n) \le \frac{m}{2(n-m+1)}$$

and using these bounds on the upper and lower bounds we wrote down for $f(n)$ gives

$$\boxed{ 4^m \left( 1 - \frac{m}{2(n-m+1)} \right) \le f(n) \le 4^m \exp \left( - \frac{m}{2n} \right) }.$$

Together with the fact that $\exp(-x) \approx 1 - x$ for $x$ small, this tells us that $f(n)$ is approximately $4^m \left( 1 - \frac{m}{2n} \right)$ for large $n$, even if $m$ is also large, as long as it's not too large compared to $n$ (more precisely, as long as $\frac{m}{n} \to 0$). For example we could take $m, n \to \infty$ with $m \sim \sqrt{n}$ and we'd get $f(n) \approx 4^{\sqrt{n}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}} \right)$!

---

There are many more delights to be found in the wild world of asymptotics of combinatorial sequences; for a nice place to start you might try reading Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's *[Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025)*, and if you really want to dive into the deep end you can try dipping your toes into Flajolet and Sedgewick's masterpiece *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html)* (decidedly *not* high school level even in the loosest sense but contains many amazing examples and very much worth reading and rereading over years; I've been slowly working through it for at least a decade). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Your ‘ *first law* ’ is just a consequence of Stirling's approximation :

$\dfrac{n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}e^{\frac1{12n+1}}<n!<\dfrac{n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}e^{\frac1{12n}}\;\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\mathbb N\!=\!\mathbb Z^+.\;\;\color{blue}{(*)}$

From the inequalities $\,(*)\,,\,$ it follows that

$\dfrac{\dfrac{\left(2n\right)^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{e^{2n}}e^\frac1{24n+1}}{\dfrac{n^{2n}\left(2\pi n\right)}{e^{2n}}e^\frac1{6n}}\!<\!\dfrac{\left(2n\right)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}\!<\!\dfrac{\dfrac{\left(2n\right)^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{e^{2n}}e^\frac1{24n}}{\dfrac{n^{2n}\left(2\pi n\right)}{e^{2n}}e^\frac2{12n+1}}\;,\;\;\forall\,n\in\mathbb N\;,$

$\displaystyle\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}e^{\frac1{24n+1}-\frac1{6n}}<\binom{2n}n<\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}e^{\frac1{24n}-\frac2{12n+1}}\;,\quad\forall\,n\in\mathbb N\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}e^{-\frac1{6n}}<\binom{2n}n<\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\;\;,\;\;\quad\forall\,n\in\mathbb N\;.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

Let $\,m\,$ be any integer $\,\big(m\in\mathbb Z\big)\,$.

Let $\;\mathbb N_m^*=\big\{n\,\big|\,n\in\mathbb N\,\land\,n\geqslant m+1\big\}\subseteq\mathbb N\,.$

From the inequalities $\,(1)\,,\,$ it follows that

$\displaystyle\dfrac{4^{n-m}}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n\!-\!m\right)}}e^{-\frac1{6\left(n-m\right)}}\!<\!\binom{2n\!-\!2m}{n\!-\!m}\!<\!\dfrac{4^{n-m}}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n\!-\!m\right)}}\,,\;\forall\,n\!\in\!\mathbb N_m^*\,.\;\color{blue}{(2)}$

Moreover, from the inequalities $\,(1)\,$ and $\,(2)\,,\,$ it follows that

$\dfrac{\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}e^{-\frac1{6n}}}{\dfrac{4^{n-m}}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n\!-\!m\right)}}}\!<\!\dfrac{\displaystyle\binom{2n}n}{\displaystyle\binom{2n\!-\!2m}{n\!-\!m}}\!<\!\dfrac{\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}}{\dfrac{4^{n-m}}{\sqrt{\pi\!\left(n\!-\!m\right)}}e^{-\frac1{6\left(n-m\right)}}}\,,\;\;\forall\,n\!\in\!\mathbb N_m^*\;,$

$4^m\!\sqrt{1\!-\!\dfrac mn}\,e^{-\frac1{6n}}\!<\!\dfrac{\displaystyle\binom{2n}n}{\displaystyle\binom{2n\!-\!2m}{n\!-\!m}}\!<4^m\!\sqrt{1\!-\!\dfrac mn}\,e^{\frac1{6\left(n-m\right)}},\;\forall\,n\!\in\!\mathbb N_m^*\,.$

Since $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(\!4^m\!\sqrt{1\!-\!\dfrac mn}\,e^{-\frac1{6n}}\!\right)=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(\!4^m\!\sqrt{1\!-\!\dfrac mn}\,e^{\frac1{6\left(n-m\right)}}\!\right)=4^m\,,\,$

from the previous inequalities, by using Squeeze Theorem, it follows that

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle\binom{2n}n}{\displaystyle\binom{2n\!-\!2m}{n\!-\!m}}=4^m\;.$

Comment: This is overkill. The factorials mostly cancel!

Comment: I know it, but I just want to point out that actually the ‘*first law*‘ of the original poster is a consequence of Stirling's approximation. My intention is not to write the shortest proof.